# Vue component not registering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vue-component

I am using Vue.JS in a project where I am trying to load a custom component tag.

We have used Vue.JS in other projects before so I basically copy pasted it into a new project though it is not working, so I assume that I missed something...

My browser console returns this error:
[console error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPFQD.png)

The code below is from my **app.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Insights from './components/insight-list.vue';
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#roots',

  components: {
    Insights
  }
});
```

And this code is from my vue component (**insight-list.vue**)

```
<template>
    <div class="insight-list">

      <h1>Hello world</h1>

    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        name: 'insight-list',

        props: [
        ],

        computed: {
        },

        methods: {
        },

        components: {
        }
    }
</script>
```

So here remains my question, what did I do wrong / what didn't I do yet?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try

```
new Vue({
  el: '#roots',

  components: {
    'insight-list': Insights
  }
});
```

source: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html

"For each property in the components object, the key will be the name of the custom element, while the value will contain the options object for the component."